# What is the difference between CURLOPT_SSLKEY and CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342880/uploading-with-sftp-curlopt-sslkey-is-not-used) and, to try to find the mistake, went to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) where I seen those 2 options :

> **CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE**   The file name for your private key. If
>   not used, libcurl defaults to $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa if the HOME
>   environment variable is set, and just "id_dsa" in the current
>   directory if HOME is not set. If the file is password-protected, set
>   the password with CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD.
>
> **CURLOPT_SSLKEY**    The name of a file containing a private SSL key.

OP of that question uses a `CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE` so I guess it should uses a `CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE` instead of a `CURLOPT_SSLKEY`, but I don't really know the difference between those options.

So here comes my question :

> What is the difference between CURLOPT_SSLKEY and
>   CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the difference between SSH and SSL in this [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/what-is-the-difference-between-ssl-vs-ssh-which-is-more-secure) question.

[Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin) answered :

> SSL and SSH both provide the cryptographic elements to build a tunnel
>   for confidential data transport with checked integrity. For that part,
>   they use similar techniques, and may suffer from the same kind of
>   attacks, so they should provide similar security (i.e. good security)
>   assuming they are both properly implemented. That both exist is a kind
>   of NIH syndrome: the SSH developers should have reused SSL for the
>   tunnel part (the SSL protocol is flexible enough to accommodate many
>   variations, including not using certificates).
>
> They differ on the things which are around the tunnel. SSL
>   traditionally uses X.509 certificates for announcing server and client
>   public keys; SSH has its own format. Also, SSH comes with a set of
>   protocols for what goes inside the tunnel (multiplexing several
>   transfers, performing password-based authentication within the tunnel,
>   terminal management...) while there is no such thing in SSL, or, more
>   accurately, when such things are used in SSL they are not considered
>   to be part of SSL (for instance, when doing password-based HTTP
>   authentication in a SSL tunnel, we say that it is part of "HTTPS", but
>   it really works in a way similar to what happens with SSH).
>
> Conceptually, you could take SSH and replace the tunnel part with the
>   one from SSL. You could also take HTTPS and replace the SSL thing with
>   SSH-with-data-transport and a hook to extract the server public key
>   from its certificate. There is no scientific impossibility and, if
>   done properly, security would remain the same. However, there is no
>   widespread set of conventions or existing tools for that.
>
> So we do not use SSL and SSH for the same things, but that's because
>   of what tools historically came with the implementations of those
>   protocols, not due to a security related difference. And whoever
>   implements SSL or SSH would be well advised to look at what kind of
>   attacks were tried on both protocols.

I am now able to answer the question without guessing :-)